# Need some information on Document Viewer in asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, documentviewer

I m trying to prepare a document viewer in asp.net 4.0. My requirement for this viewer is that all users coming to my website will be able to view every document. uploaded by him on my web-server.

I want to know any third party free application/service/user-control i can use in my website and open all my documents (.doc, .docx, .xls, .xlsx, .ppt, .pptx, .pdf, .jpg, .gif, and other image formats.)

I found Adeptol Viewer, TX  TextControl. but this are very costly, ranging $5000 and above. can i get any cheap control..

**EDIT :** Also i want to know, is it possible to create such custom control in .NET and use it for our future use. If possible please guide me how i can achieve this. It is fine I can use Client Scripting like jQuery. for this

Awaiting for the reply from any technical experts who is willing to help/ support my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the best and free solution for document viewer for all types of documents including edit feature..

- Google Docs viewer
- Zoho viewer

I found Zoho more interesting than google as it provides fantastic features compared to google.. editing of any document (.ppt or .xls) is just like you are using Microsoft Office in your browser.

Fantastic functionality and perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is open source document viewer named [Okyanux File Manager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/oxfilemanager/) supporting only the documents which browsers support such as .swf, .wmv, .jpg, .gif and other image formats. You can also add .pdf support with Ron Schuler's open source [PDF Viewer](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/aspnetpdfviewer.aspx). It converts pdf files to images for previewing. I think other file types are not easy. You can add word and excel support with [Spire.XLS](http://www.zimbio.com/Microsoft+Excel/articles/oSU16Hrbx1c/C+Convert+Excel+to+Image) which costs 900$.